# Getting a black screen after save photo - Android Camera

Tags: android, camera, screen, photo

I'm developing an application for Android that captures max fps and saves to the SD card.

The problem is that the saved photo is a black screen, and I can't understand why.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

The code where I do this:

```
public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment {
private Camera cam;
private CameraPreview camPreview;
private boolean recording = false;
private ArrayList<byte[]> fotos;
private ArrayList<String> tempos;
private Thread thread;

public PhotoFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photofinish, container, false);
    cam = getCameraInstance();
    if(cam != null) {
        cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);

        // set Camera parameters
        Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = cam.getParameters();

        //set color efects to none
        cameraParameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);

        //set antibanding to none
        if (cameraParameters.getAntibanding() != null) {
            cameraParameters.setAntibanding(Camera.Parameters.ANTIBANDING_OFF);
        }

        // set white ballance
        if (cameraParameters.getWhiteBalance() != null) {
            cameraParameters.setWhiteBalance(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_CLOUDY_DAYLIGHT);
        }

        //set flash
        if (cameraParameters.getFlashMode() != null) {
            cameraParameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }

        //set zoom
        if (cameraParameters.isZoomSupported()) {
            cameraParameters.setZoom(0);
        }

        //set focus mode
        cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_INFINITY);

        List<Size> sizes = cameraParameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
        Camera.Size size = sizes.get(0);
        cameraParameters.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
        cam.setParameters(cameraParameters);
        fotos = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        tempos = new ArrayList<String>();
        camPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), cam);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(camPreview);
        TextView startRecording = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.start_record_button);
        startRecording.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!recording)
                {
                    recording = true;   
                    Size previewSize = cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
                    int dataBufferSize=(int)(previewSize.height*previewSize.width*(ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(cam.getParameters().getPreviewFormat())/8.0));
                    thread.start();
                    cam.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
                    cam.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
                    cam.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
                    cam.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {
                        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] imageData, Camera arg1) {
                            try {                                   
                                fotos.add(imageData);
                                tempos.add(new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss_SSS", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("ERRO: " + e);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    recording = false;
                    try {
                        thread.join();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            }               
        });
        thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  while(recording) {
                      if(fotos.size()>0 && tempos.size()>0)
                      {
                          File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(1, tempos.get(0));
                            if (pictureFile == null){
                                System.out.println("Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
                                return;
                            }

                            try {               
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                                fos.write(fotos.get(0));
                                fos.close();
                                pictureFile = null;
                                cam.addCallbackBuffer(fotos.get(0));
                                fotos.remove(0);
                                tempos.remove(0);           
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                System.out.println("ERRO FILE NOT FOUND! : " + e);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                System.out.println("ERRO IOException!");
                            }
                      }
                  }

              }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Camera not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return rootView;
}

public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    }
    catch (Exception e){

    }
    return c;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    cam.release();
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type, String timeStamp){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "L_P");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            System.out.println("L_P failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStampDay = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + timeStampDay).mkdirs();

    File mediaFile;
    if (type == 1){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + timeStampDay + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == 2) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are claiming that the file is a JPEG. However, you have done nothing to convert the image to be a JPEG. Preview frames, by default, are not JPEG, but are in [NV21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21) format. Use `getSupportedPreviewFormats()` to see if JPEG previews are possible, then use `setPreviewFormat()` to request JPEG previews.

And, as I noted in your previous question, do **NOT** have two threads working with an `ArrayList`. Also, do **not** have your background thread busy-wait looking constantly for an image to show up on an `ArrayList`. Use a `LinkedBlockingQueue` or something else that is thread-safe and allows the background thread to block while waiting for an image.

Comment: thanks for your help! Now I'm converting NV21 to JPEG and the photos are working fine.
Today I will change the arraylist to LinkedBlockingQueue. Now I've another question: I'm trying to get previews and discard it (just to see how many fps i can get), and I can't get more than 16/17 fps. 
I've downloaded an app that can get 27/28 fps from my smartphone. Do  know why?
Thank You again! :)

Comment: @user2989493: You may need to add a couple of more buffers via `addCallbackBuffer()`. If a preview frame comes in, and all of your existing buffers are in use, that frame is dropped. You can't go crazy and add a 100 buffers, as you will run out of memory. But you could experiment by adding a fourth, then a fifth, etc. until you get to a point where adding more buffers does not help.

Comment: I've added two and three more buffers and the number of fps stills the same. But I tried with just one buffer, and the number of fps is the same the with three and more buffers. Is this normal?

Comment: @user2989493: I can't really answer that, sorry. It does not sound right.